# How to run multiple Copy Files task in a Azure DevOps Release pipeline simultaneously with Custom Conditions?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am using Azure DevOps Server 2020 and I have a release pipeline which has around 21 copy file tasks in it to copy the output of multiple microservices to different target paths and this takes almost around 23 mins to complete the release pipeline.

I want to optimize the release pipeline and save some time and thus I am thinking of running all the copy task simultaneously.

Under the copy tasks in Control Options section, I see Run this task option is available where we do have the option to define custom conditions but I am not sure which custom conditions do I need to define exactly so that all my copy tasks gets executed parallelly.

Could anyone please let me know what custom conditions will allow all the copy task to get executed in one go?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to have tasks run in parallel. It has been raised as a suggestion [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ability-to-run-tasks-in-parallel/365659) but the feature hasn't been implemented

Answer (score 0):

> How to run multiple Copy Files task in a Azure DevOps Release pipeline simultaneously with Custom Conditions?

Just as TheWinterCoder pointed, Currently it is not possible to have tasks run in parallel.

But, as a workaround, you could divide the replication task into several different jobs and make the jobs run in parallel:

[image]

This requires you to have multiple agents available in the local agent pool:

[image]